# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 won't start

Tags: gnome, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 on VirtualBox with an image from osboxes.org

Updated last night. Today, it won't start. It hangs at various points during boot up, with messages such as

```
A start job is running for Daily apt activities ( 55s / no limit )

[ OK ] Created slice system-getty.slice


Started User Manager for UID 120
Stopping User Manager for UID 120
Stopped User Manager for UID 120
Removed slice User Slice of gdm
```

What's the best way to proceed?  Obviously I could just delete the VM and create another but it could well just do the same again.

Heynnema suggested booting from a live CD and running `fsck`

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

**Edit 2**

```
carl@osboxes:~$ dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii
carl@osboxes:~$
```

Does not return anything, but ...

```
carl@osboxes:~$ dpkg -l *virtualbox* 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: Can you get  to the GRUB menu and recovery mode? Do you have access to a Ubuntu Live .iso?

Comment: The GRUB menu is not shown.  I *could* get a Live iso, whether I can get a VM to boot off that is something I'll have to check.

Comment: "Insert" the .iso into the VM CD drive and boot to it. Try and run `fsck` from that. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema See edit.

Comment: This question https://askubuntu.com/questions/908841/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-boot-failure-in-virtualbox-after-installing-guest-additions appears to describe the same problem.

Comment: Start `gparted` and determine which partition on /dev/sda is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition. Lets say it turns out to be sda5. Then `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`. Report back.

Comment: I uninstalled VirtualBox Guest Additions as per the question I linked to above, and it's now working again. It appears to be a  bug with VirtualBox.

Comment: Show me `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`. Did you run `fsck`? What's different about the image from osboxes.org?

Comment: @heynnema See edit.  Didn't run `fsck` as the other solution worked.  AFAIK the images from osboxes.org are just ready-installed for convenience; they skip the installation procedure.

Comment: You lost me. The dpkg command shows that VirtualBox isn't installed. I thought this was a VB problem? Which other solution "worked"? I don't think it's a VB Guest Additions problem.

Comment: No, VirtualBox isn't installed on the VM itself. The solution that worked was CTRL+ALT+F2 and running the Guest Additions uninstall script from the VB directory in /opt

Comment: Worked for me Carl..... that should be an answer not a comment :)